# NetSuite Advanced PDF Multiplication

Tags: freemarker, netsuite

Looking for a way to multiply the rate * quantity in an advanced pdf form.

Using ${item.rate}*${item.quantity} print 100*10 instead of 1000.  I know I can grab the amount field but I have a custom quantity field set up that I am using so need to calculate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:  `${item.rate*item.quantity}`

Comment: Right, basically you've got the `*` outside of any Freemarker expression, so it will just be interpreted as text.

Comment: Thanks man, I think I tried about every combo but that.  Makes sense, I didn't see this spelled out clearly anywhere in the freemarker documentation so appreciate it.